# No aparece el contenido en mi pagina web

Tags: web, hosting, localhost

Buen dia mi error es que en el local Host todo se visualiza de forma correcta, pero en la URL, no aparece el contenido de algunas secciones

LocalHost:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZINy.png

Web:

[www.polarprintco.com](http://www.polarprintco.com)

*La pagina me reporta algunos errores pero resulta que son los mismos archivos que tengo para el localhost*

Estructura:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KmxN.png

Index:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UMxs.png

*/Agradeceria mucho la ayuda*/

Comment: Deberías agregar mas detalles, por ejemplo los mensajes de error que obtienes

Comment: estos son los errores que me aparecen

Comment: https://ibb.co/ZLGng0Z

Comment: Los mensajes de error van como texto en la pregunta, por favor evita el excesivo uso de imágenes

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/polanjtp/public_html/models/conexion.php:9 Stack trace: #0 /home/polanjtp/public_html/models/conexion.php(9): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'adz11226336', Array) #1 /home/polanjtp/public_html/models/gestorSlide.php(11): Conexion::conectar() #2 /home/polanjtp/public_html/controllers/gestorSlide.php(9): SlideModels::seleccionarSlideModel('slide') #3 /home/polanjtp/public_html/views/includes/banner.php(10): Slide->nivoSlideController() #4

Comment: /home/polanjtp/public_html/views/modules/inicio.php(14): include('/home/polanjtp/...') #5 /home/polanjtp/public_html/controllers/controller.php(45): include('/home/polanjtp/...') #6 /home/polanjtp/public_html/views/template.php(67): MvcController::enlacesPaginasController() #7 /home/polanjtp/public_html/controllers/controller.php(22): include('/home/polanjtp/...') #8 /home/polanjtp/public_html/index.php(30): MvcController->plantilla() #9 {main} in /home/polanjtp/public_html/models/conexion.php on line 9

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente el error

> 28000 1045

con

> using password: YES

se debe a falta de comillas

> "

en el segmento de la contraseña de la conexion a la DB.

1. encontre la misma referencia de error resulta aqui: [Solucion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325115/sqlstate28000-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password).
2. aqui otra igual con el mismo numero de error: [Solucion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57356168/sqlstate28000-1045-access-denied-for-user-elsharkawyazq-climate-applocal).

espero sea ese tu problema.

Comment: no amigo no me funciono =(

Comment: puedes mostrar que hay en la linea 9 de conexion.php??